# 2D Array or Map to store values against weekdays and slots within days

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to increment values for days of week and slots within each day, i.e. Morning, Afternoon, Evening and Night, as I iterate over a collection where I get the time and then evaluate which timeslot the time is in.
I need to be able to iterate over the end result in the front end but want a nicer solution that the one i currently have represented but the totals array. It has been suggested I use a map but unsure of how to implement this with a map.

```
   var totals = [
    //  Tot M  T  W  T  F  S  S
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    // Totals
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    // Morning
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    // Afternoon
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    // Evening
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]     // Night
];



var collectionOfData = entiredataset;


collectionOfData.forEach(function (item) {
    var localDate = getLocalDate(item);//gets users local date and determines timeslot id - ie Morning,afternoon, evening, or night
    var dayOfWeek = localDate.day();
    var timeslotId = item.timeslotId;

    totals[timeslotId][dayOfWeek]++;  // Increase sessions per slot and day
    totals[0][dayOfWeek]++;           // Increase total sessions per day
    totals[timeslotId][0]++;    // Increase total sessions per slot
    totals[0][0]++;             // Increase total sessions

    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways I would design the data structure is as follows - see demo with input, output and total calculation methods:

```js
var slots={'Monday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},'Tuesday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},'Wednessday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},'Thursday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},'Friday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},'Saturday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},'Sunday':{'Morning':0,'Afernoon':0,'Evening':0,'Night':0},}

// input data
function insertSlotFor(day, slot) {
  slots[day][slot]++;
}

// output data
function getSlotFor(day, slot) {
  return slots[day][slot];
}

// get total for a day
function totalForDay(day) {
  return Object.keys(slots[day]).reduce(function(prev,curr){
    return prev + slots[day][curr];
  },0);
}

// get total for a slot
function totalForSlot(slot) {
  return Object.keys(slots).reduce(function(prev,curr){
    return prev + slots[curr][slot];
  },0);
}

insertSlotFor('Monday', 'Morning');
insertSlotFor('Monday', 'Night');
insertSlotFor('Tuesday', 'Morning');

console.log(slots);

console.log(totalForDay('Monday'));
console.log(totalForSlot('Morning'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an object of e.g. `DayOfWeek`, and have methods in that object that will do all that logic. This will encapsulate the logic and make it easier to manage the code. Then, your array will hold instances of that object, and you will just refer to objects by their index (`dayOfWeek`) and call methods to get the totals.

Your `getLocalDate()` function should do what it says - get data, and not set anything (i.e. `timeslotId`) in the item. This is confusing and mixes responsibilities. It can be a method of the `DayOfWeek` object, who's constructor will get an item and return the values as needed.